# Firebase hosting not connecting to custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a working blahblah.firebaseapp.com default domain working correctly. No problems there. My website was on another provider so I went through the process to connect it to firebase hosting. Everything went fine and the domain status in Firebase Hosting console shows connected for my blahblah.com and www.blahblah.com domains. My problem is that when I navigate to blahblah.com, I get a page that says

[image: Firebase Image]

I can't find anyone with quite the same issue on Stackoverflow or any other site. There was one that was fixed by opening in a different browser (cached site issue), but this isn't my problem. I have double checked the DNS settings from my provider. Everything checks out. It's been close to 20 hours since I have completed the verification and the status shows connected in firebase hosting. I even re-deployed my site to firebase to see if that would reset something. Didn't help.

So now what should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you initialized your project with default values, your `public` directory is what get's served. So, edit or add the `index.html` file in your `public` folder then `firebase deploy`. You should now be able to see your custom HTML.

Comment: index.html is in the public folder. Additionally, the .firebaseapp.com default url works, but the custom domain, which should connect to that, doesn't. How would this apply to my issue? Wouldn't this problem be apparent in the default url as well?

Comment: What Ron is saying is that this page (Welcome - Firebase Hosting Setup Complete, etc) is actually the index.html page. So just change the content of this page, re-deploy, and you will see a different "home" page for your app.

Comment: You pointed me the right way. The index.html in the public folder was not the issue, it was the index in the build folder. When I did firebase init, I clicked y for overwriting the index.html. My mistake. Still not sure why the .firebaseapp and the custom domain weren't matching up, but now that I went through the process (build, init, deploy), it is all good now. Accepted answer since it was essentially correct and helped me find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same issue, experimented a bit and found the solution.

**Case 1-** You want your website to be served at `subdomain.domain.tld` as will as on `domain.tld`, but added only `subdomain.domain.tld` as custom domain on firebase hosting dashboard.

- In this case the address `domain.tld` will throw an error.
- To get rid of this error add another custom domain in your firebase
  hosting    dashboard as `domain.tld`

**Case- 2-** You want your website to be served over `domain.tld` but also accessible through `subdomain.domain.tld`

- Add both the domains in custom domain field.
- Edit `subdomain.domain.tld` to redirect at `domain.tld`.

**Case- 3-** You want your website to be served over `subdomain.domain.tld` but also accessible through `domain.tld`

- Add both the domains in custom domain field.
- Edit  `domain.tld` to redirect at `subdomain.domain.tld`.